# How to add tooltip to a react + d3 grouped and stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a created a stacked and grouped bar chart with react + d3 and i want to add tooltip, i have tried different ways but none of them did work. the code for tooltip looks like:

```js
const tooltip = select(svgRef.current)
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("visibility", "visible")
      .style("background-color", "black")
      .style("border", "solid")
      .style("border-width", "1px")
      .style("border-radius", "5px")
      .style("padding", "10px")
      .html("<p>I'm a tooltip written in HTML</p>");
      
    svg
      .select(".barreact")
      .on("mouseover", function () {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })
      .on("mousemove", function () {
        return tooltip
          .style("top", event.pageY + "px")
          .style("left", event.pageX + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      });
```

you can check the full code and demo in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goldwasser-2xk3p?file=/src/StackedBarGraph.js:2198-2593)

any help to make it work will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SVG `foreignObjects` to append HTML to an SVG:

```
const tooltip = select(svg)
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", 180);

const tooltipDiv = tooltip
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .html("<p>I'm a tooltip written in HTML</p>");
```

Note that we only set the width. [The height is calculated dynamically by looking at the height of the div with the width set](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411): you can also do the opposite, setting an height and introspecting for the width:

```
  bars.on("mousemove", function () {
    const htmlContentHeight = tooltipDiv.node().getBoundingClientRect()
      .height;
    tooltip.attr("height", htmlContentHeight);
    tooltip.raise();
    return tooltip
      .attr("x", event.pageX)
      .attr("y", event.pageY - htmlContentHeight);
  })
```

Since SVG has no z-index, we must put the last element at the top of the SVG, and we can do so with `selection.raise`.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-browser-z20e1)